# How to supports many title in one article?

Tags: titles

[image: solution]

I used the above solution described in [How to create pdf from Linux man pages so that style is presereved?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390724/how-to-create-pdf-from-linux-man-pages-so-that-style-is-presereved). I have two files `bcopy.3.gz.tex`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{\usepackage{microtype}}{}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={},
            pdftitle={BCOPY(3)},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

% Set background colour (of the page)
\definecolor{weirdbgcolor}{HTML}{FCF4F0}
\pagecolor{weirdbgcolor}

% Make bold text appear in a particular colour
\definecolor{boldcolor}{HTML}{6E0002}
\let\realtextbf=\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\textcolor{boldcolor}{\realtextbf{#1}}}

% Use underlines instead of emphasis (ugh)
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\underline{#1}}

% % Use fixed-width font by default
% \renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\title{BCOPY(3)}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
BCOPY(3) & Linux Programmer's Manual & BCOPY(3)
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\hyperdef{}{NAME}{\section{\hyperref[NAME]{NAME}}\label{NAME}}

bcopy - copy byte sequence

\hyperdef{}{SYNOPSIS}{\section{\hyperref[SYNOPSIS]{SYNOPSIS}}\label{SYNOPSIS}}

\begin{verbatim}
#include <strings.h>
 
void bcopy(const void *src, void *dest, size_t n);
\end{verbatim}

\hyperdef{}{DESCRIPTION}{\section{\hyperref[DESCRIPTION]{DESCRIPTION}}\label{DESCRIPTION}}

The \textbf{bcopy}() function copies \emph{n} bytes from \emph{src} to
\emph{dest}. The result is correct, even when both areas overlap.

\hyperdef{}{RETURNux5fVALUE}{\section{\hyperref[RETURNux5fVALUE]{RETURN
VALUE}}\label{RETURNux5fVALUE}}

None.

\hyperdef{}{CONFORMINGux5fTO}{\section{\hyperref[CONFORMINGux5fTO]{CONFORMING
TO}}\label{CONFORMINGux5fTO}}

4.3BSD. This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001):
use \textbf{memcpy}(3) or \textbf{memmove}(3) in new programs. Note that
the first two arguments are interchanged for \textbf{memcpy}(3) and
\textbf{memmove}(3). POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of
\textbf{bcopy}().

\hyperdef{}{SEEux5fALSO}{\section{\hyperref[SEEux5fALSO]{SEE
ALSO}}\label{SEEux5fALSO}}

\textbf{memccpy}(3), \textbf{memcpy}(3), \textbf{memmove}(3),
\textbf{strcpy}(3), \textbf{strncpy}(3)

\hyperdef{}{COLOPHON}{\section{\hyperref[COLOPHON]{COLOPHON}}\label{COLOPHON}}

This page is part of release 3.54 of the Linux \emph{man-pages} project.
A description of the project, and information about reporting bugs, can
be found at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
2009-03-15 & Linux
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

and `bcmp.3.gz.tex`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{\usepackage{microtype}}{}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={},
            pdftitle={BCMP(3)},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

% Set background colour (of the page)
\definecolor{weirdbgcolor}{HTML}{FCF4F0}
\pagecolor{weirdbgcolor}

% Make bold text appear in a particular colour
\definecolor{boldcolor}{HTML}{6E0002}
\let\realtextbf=\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\textcolor{boldcolor}{\realtextbf{#1}}}

% Use underlines instead of emphasis (ugh)
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\underline{#1}}

% % Use fixed-width font by default
% \renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\title{BCMP(3)}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
BCMP(3) & Linux Programmer's Manual & BCMP(3)
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\hyperdef{}{NAME}{\section{\hyperref[NAME]{NAME}}\label{NAME}}

bcmp - compare byte sequences

\hyperdef{}{SYNOPSIS}{\section{\hyperref[SYNOPSIS]{SYNOPSIS}}\label{SYNOPSIS}}

\begin{verbatim}
#include <strings.h>
 
int bcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
\end{verbatim}

\hyperdef{}{DESCRIPTION}{\section{\hyperref[DESCRIPTION]{DESCRIPTION}}\label{DESCRIPTION}}

The \textbf{bcmp}() function compares the two byte sequences \emph{s1}
and \emph{s2} of length \emph{n} each. If they are equal, and in
particular if \emph{n} is zero, \textbf{bcmp}() returns 0. Otherwise it
returns a nonzero result.

\hyperdef{}{RETURNux5fVALUE}{\section{\hyperref[RETURNux5fVALUE]{RETURN
VALUE}}\label{RETURNux5fVALUE}}

The \textbf{bcmp}() function returns 0 if the byte sequences are equal,
otherwise a nonzero result is returned.

\hyperdef{}{CONFORMINGux5fTO}{\section{\hyperref[CONFORMINGux5fTO]{CONFORMING
TO}}\label{CONFORMINGux5fTO}}

4.3BSD. This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001):
use \textbf{memcmp}(3) in new programs. POSIX.1-2008 removes the
specification of \textbf{bcmp}().

\hyperdef{}{SEEux5fALSO}{\section{\hyperref[SEEux5fALSO]{SEE
ALSO}}\label{SEEux5fALSO}}

\textbf{memcmp}(3), \textbf{strcasecmp}(3), \textbf{strcmp}(3),
\textbf{strcoll}(3), \textbf{strncasecmp}(3), \textbf{strncmp}(3)

\hyperdef{}{COLOPHON}{\section{\hyperref[COLOPHON]{COLOPHON}}\label{COLOPHON}}

This page is part of release 3.54 of the Linux \emph{man-pages} project.
A description of the project, and information about reporting bugs, can
be found at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
2008-08-06 & Linux
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I have done followings -

```
sed -i '/begin{document}/d' bcmp.3.gz.tex
sed -i '/end{document}/d' bcopy.3.gz.tex
sed -i 1,61d bcmp.3.gz.tex
cat bcopy.3.gz.tex bcmp.3.gz.tex > new.tex
pdflatex new.tex
evince new.pdf
```

Result is -
[image]
[image]
Although the `BCMP` is declared as title it is shifted to left. I want to put it in middle to keep similar pattern of all title.

This may be done by `book` or `report` class. But @ShreevatsaR sulution's return `article` by default.

Comment: Please always post a MWE here.

Comment: @TeXnician why you want MWE. I provide all things.

Comment: Well, because I can't take some code from this post and just copy it to my editor and compile. As we are all doing this for free here it is the concept of help others help you.

Comment: @TeXnician see I edited the question.

Comment: Ah, so with article and that setup you should have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/two-maketitles-in-article

Comment: @alhelal: The default behaviour is to destroy `\maketitle` (and most things associated with it) after the first use. If you want more than one `\maketitle`, consider using the [`titling` package](//ctan.org/pkg/titling).

Comment: Yes, `titling` package solves my problem.

Comment: `scrartcl` (a dop-in replacement for `article`) does also provide several usage of `\maketitle` since version 3.12.

Comment: Off-Topic: `fixltx2e` is not needed since LaTeX 2015/01/01. And instead of setting `\parskip` and `\parindent` you should consider to use [package `parskip`](https://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) or a class that does support paragraph separation by skip on its own.

Comment: BTW: [`subfiles`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) or [`combine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/combine) could be useful for compiling either single documents or one large document.